# How can I know which minimum MATLAB version is required to run a script/function?

Tags: matlab

I have written a MATLAB script/function: How can I know which minimum MATLAB version is required to run it? (without having to run it on different MATLAB versions)

Comment: Check the documentation for the old version. http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/doc-archives.html

Comment: How does this help? I have written the code, it's not some MATLAB function.

Comment: You have to try out with older versions or check the documentation for the called functions.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think there's any way of knowing which version is required to run a particular piece of code. The only way to know for sure is try it.

Comment: Unfortunately MATLAB doesn't document the date when functions were changed or newly implemented at a central place. Scanning individual release notes is a pain... I'd recommend testing the oldest and newest matlab version you're having in mind.

Comment: To strengthen the point of @am304: There is probably not even a way to check whether the code will work fully for the current version, unless you can try every possible combination of inputs.

Comment: [This summary](http://www.dynare.org/DynareWiki/MatlabVersionsCompatibility) of when some major functions and features were introduced is sometimes helpful. Otherwise, if you really want to be sure that code returns identical results, you need to run it in the old versions.

Comment: @horchler Wow, great page! Thanks! Bookmarking that one.

Answer (score 3):

If you have recently written it, hopefully the code is still fresh in your mind.

In this case I would recommend grabbing the release notes, and start reading backwards untill you find a new feature that you used.

For most of my code fragments the backwards compatibility stops at the point where `~` is not allowed as output, where `sort` only has one possible output argument. Or where `rng` did not exist yet. I would look into at least these points as they are quite significant changes.

---

If you are not willing to try a lot of runs for different versions: Just make a guess.
If it runs on an old version, and on a new version, it is very likely that it will also run on all versions in between. If it is a one time question and the code is simple to run, but you just don't want to get an old matlab version, you could consider contacting Mathworks support and ask them to try it.

Sidenote: If you are only worried about the validity of the syntax, it may be sufficient do dig up old `mlint` versions rather than full installations?

Comment: +1 Note also that [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) changed its behaviour on R2013a. That has given me trouble in the past